# Retrieving a Value inside of AsyncTask method in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am implementing JSON array which I retrieved using AsyncTask method for background process,

I have an array variable which is declared before OnCreate and initialized with some value,

```
String [] str=new String[100];
```

Storing in tat array variable while parsing the json array like this in a for loop,

```
str[i]=c.getString(TAG_NAME);
```

storing perfectly, I did Log and its showing in logcat too,

but the problem is when I use "str" array variable outside of my function like this,

```
void func()
{
List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int x=0;x<str.length;x++)
{

    top250.add(str[x]);

}
}
```

The str variable is storing only the string "null" for initialized memory.

It's storing "null" for 100 times.

So how to fetch the value which is processed in doInBackground method inside of AsyncTask?

Comment: At first you should explain some terms you use. What do you mean by "global" variable? Is it instance variable? What do you mean by "use the "str" array variable outside of my funtion like this,"? 
Although I don't fully understand your question, I think that you are trying to execute an asynctask and "right after )}.execute();" you call some other function. This wont work as asynctask runs in separate thread and that's why you get null right after asynctask execution. You should do all your work with an str array either at the and of doInBackground or in onPostExecute(...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return your list of strings in post execute()

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int x=0;x<str.length;x++)
        {

            top250.add(str[x]);

        }

        return top250;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {

        //validate result and assign to something useful like a field

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

Then you could assign result to a field somewhere in your class after validating it.

Comment: Going from a List to an Array is not an issue as you can convert easily. Foo[] array = list.toArray(new Foo[list.size()]);

Comment: @Brendon thanks. Take a look at GSON from Google. It will save you a lot of work with your JSON deserialisation and make things go quicker. https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: How to implement this gson? any projects link? @Graham

Comment: @Brendon see my link https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/, you can download and include the jar in your project.

Comment: i am successfully fetching the value, thanks and kudos, but how can i fetch two different variables?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
Asyntask Example for reference [Code and concept here](http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/01/asynctask-android-example.html).

As we Know AsynTask has three parameters

```
new `AsynTask < Params , Progress , Result >`
```

You can do Like This:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                             //Parse your json here
                             //You will get this result into result of onPostExceute()

                                       return json;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                                        //Use your result here
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                }
                      }.execute();
```

Using this you can get your String(here) or WhatEver you defined into Result Section of `AsynTask`

Hope this could Help